# for-loop condition ignored when comparing to negative integer

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, expression, implicit-conversion

While writing a function to count in how many individual position the string `sub` appears in the string `s` i found that the for-loop didn't work when using the empty string as `s`.

```
char* s = "";
char* sub = "up";

for(int i = 0; i <= (strlen(s) - strlen(sub)); i++){

    //stuff
}
```

In this case the loop kept going as if the condition wasn't met.

However if i rewrite the condition this way it works as intended.

```
int max = strlen(s) - strlen(sub);

for(int i = 0; i <= max; i++){

   //stuff
}
```

So i was wondering what is it that could cause this kind of behaviour.

Comment: `strlen` returns an unsigned value.

Comment: `unsigned max = strlen(s) - strlen(sub);` gives max = 4294967294

Comment: To which number do you expect the expression `strlen(s) - strlen(sub)` to evaluate, in your example? Is it `2`? Or is it `-2`?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Should be -2, but now i know the issue is about `strlen` returning an unsigned int.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Whether `strlen` returns an unsigned value is irrelevant. Whether it returns an unsigned type is critical.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Darn those important distinctions! :)

Comment: this is why those 'pesky' warnings shouldnt be ignored  "warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data"

Comment: @pm100 wouldn't ignore one, i didn't see any tho.

Comment: @Vly you see I pasted the warning from my compiler tho, (mabe turn your warning level up)

Comment: @pm100 And there it was, tried with gcc -Wextra and it came out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the condition of the for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i <= (strlen(s) - strlen(sub)); i++){

    //stuff
}
```

the both expressions `strlen( s )` and `strlen( sub )` have the unsigned integer type `size_t`. So the expression `strlen(s) - strlen(sub)` also can not be negative.

As `strlen( sub )` is greater than `strlen( s )` then their difference will produce a very big value of the type `size_t`.

Try this call of printf

```
printf( "size_t( -2 ) = %zu\n", size_t( -2 ) );
```

Its output in some system can be for example the following

```
size_t( -2 ) = 4294967294
```

while the value if INT_MAX in the same system is equal to `2147483647`.

Moreover as the value `INT_MAX` is less than the obtained value of the above expression then you can get an infinite for loop.

What you need is to rewrite the condition the following way

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i  + strlen( sub ) <= strlen(s); i++){

    //stuff
}
```

Comment: Ah, i see it was pretty obvious. So what happens when i try it the second way is that the size_t value is converted in int?